# Why are certain controls losing viewstate after UpdatePanel postback?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel, viewstate

I've got several controls on a page
....
then I've got an asp:updatepanel
....
then I've got more controls after the updatepanel.

I call the updatePanel's Load event from javascript like this:

```
__doPostBack('<%=myUpdatePanel.ClientID%>','');
```

In the updatepanel's Load event, I can access all the controls above the updatepanel.  However the controls below the updatepanel have lost their values.

What's the deal, Mr. UpdatePanel Man?